# Best way to learn how to combine Blueprintcss and Compass/Sass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I would like to apply Blueprintcss and Compass/Sass to a Rails project.

Should I learn Blueprint first or Compass/Sass first or are there any guides on how to use the two of these together?

Also, does it make any difference that it's a Rails project? Could this combination of technologies be just as easily applied to, say, a Java project?

Comment: I'm using Compass/Blueprint on a ASP.NET MVC project, so no -- it doesn't make a difference what language or framework you are using.  You just need to be able to run Ruby.

Answer (score 8):

When I first encountered Compass, I knew neither Compass nor Blueprint. I started out by watching the Compass [screencast](http://vimeo.com/4335944) and then by trying to use it. As Sass is similar to CSS (CSS on steroids ;-)), I was able to get working real soon. Having the [Blueprint CSS cheat sheet](http://www.scribd.com/doc/12850249/Blueprint-CSS-framework-version-08-cheat-sheet) helped a lot. Thus, I recommend learning Compass first and then learning Blueprint on the way.

Also have a look at the [GitHub wiki pages for Compass](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass).

It is easy to use Compass with any language/framework combination.

Answer (score 3):

Compass comes with its own version of Blueprint, so I'd say just learn Compass.

Answer (score 0):

Blueprint is just predefined plain set of css. so you can use it on any frameworks or programming languages.

I my self using blueprint for both php and java project. for php i am using codeigniter, joomla and even wordpress ;)